# How can I use excel export to a paginated gridview yii2?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2, kartik-v

Good evening, everyone.
I am using **Yii2**Framework and as a result of filters, I want to export these to csv using **yii2\kartik**'s **GridView**component or using **ExportMenu**also from **yii2\kartik**.

My **dataProvider**, however, is paginated and the results, therefore, are obtained via AJAX.
Currently, I rebuild the csv file myself when I click on an "**Export**" button but this involves me rebuilding all the queries, doubling the computational time.

Is there any way to use these components with a paginated gridview?
Thank you all!

I am trying to make full use of the https://demos.krajee.com/grid component and https://demos.krajee.com/export, but I find difficulty when the dataProvider is paged.

I expect that, regardless of paging, that component will help me export the csv in one go, speeding up my execution process.

Answer (score 0):

### In Yii2 Framework, when you're using a paginated GridView with AJAX, exporting the data to CSV using Yii2 Kartik's GridView and ExportMenu components can be achieved without rebuilding queries manually. Here's how you can do it:

1. Configure GridView and ExportMenu:
   Make sure you have properly configured your GridView and ExportMenu components in your view file.

   ```
    use yii\grid\GridView;
    use kartik\export\ExportMenu;

    echo GridView::widget([
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
      'columns' => [
          // Your columns here
       ],
    ]);

    echo ExportMenu::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
         'columns' => [
              // Specify columns for export
         ],
       'target' => ExportMenu::TARGET_SELF,
       'exportConfig' => [
             ExportMenu::FORMAT_CSV => false, // CSV format
            // Other formats as needed
          ],
    ]);
   ```
2. Adjust Controller Action for Export:
   In your controller, make sure you handle the export action properly. Since your data provider is paginated, you need to fetch all data regardless of pagination.

   ```
   use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
   use yii\web\Response;

   public function actionExportCsv()
   {
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
       'query' => YourModel::find()->where(/* Add your filters */),
       'pagination' => false, // Disable pagination to fetch all data
   ]);

   $dataProvider->prepare(true);

   $csvData = $dataProvider->getModels(); // Get all data
   $csvContent = ''; // Initialize CSV content

   // Generate CSV content from data
   foreach ($csvData as $model) {
       // Process each model and format data as needed
       $csvContent .= implode(',', $model->attributes) . "\n";
   }

   // Set headers and output CSV content
   Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW;
   Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
   Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="export.csv"');
   Yii::$app->response->content = $csvContent;

   return Yii::$app->response->send();
   ```

   }
3. Configure ExportMenu to use AJAX:
   If you're using AJAX to load the GridView, you might want to configure ExportMenu to also use AJAX for export. You can do this by specifying the target property as ExportMenu::TARGET_BLANK or ExportMenu::TARGET_POPUP.

   ```
     echo ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     'columns' => [
         // Specify columns for export
      ],
      'target' => ExportMenu::TARGET_BLANK, // Use AJAX for export
      'exportConfig' => [
              ExportMenu::FORMAT_CSV => false, // CSV format
              // Other formats as needed
          ],
       ]);
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

When I use "ExportMenu" in my view, which is called via a RenderPartial, if I try to click on any export of the component it does nothing, and I didn't understand how to actually call your action and pass the gridview directly to it.

Comment: My dataProvider is an ArrayDataProvider, but I'm thinking that ExportMenu use an ArrayDataProvider. 

Can I convert an ArrayDataProvider into ActiveDataProvider?

Comment: @AlessandroPioBudetti Since ArrayDatatProvider is fed by array source data, you cannot convert it into ActiveDataProvider. You could do the other way around - take models from ActiveDataProvider and populate them into ArrayDataProvider.